# compatible comments for both bash and batch

Tags: bash, batch-file

We write two similar scripts: one for bash (linux) and one for batch (dos/windows).

Even if the specific code is different we would like to visually compare (diff) both scripts and have the similar parts of code aligned side by side.

We use explicit comments with the same text to achieve this. But the beginning of the comments is different in both scripting (`REM` or `::` in windows) and (`#` in linux).

Therefore there is a wrong alignment:

| linux | windows |
| --- | --- |
| # first step |  |
|  | REM first step |
| foo.sh | foo.bat |
| # second step |  |
|  | REM second step |
| bar.sh | bar.bat |

Is there a way to use a common character or sequence of characters to make the comments equal?

Is the use of `: #;` safe for both systems/scripts?

| linux | windows |
| --- | --- |
| : #; first step | : #; first step |
| foo.sh | foo.bat |
| : #; second step | : #; second step |
| bar.sh | bar.bat |

Are there any unwanted side effects?

Comment: Well, `::` is not a comment in batch, it is a broken label; it is sometimes (mis-)used as a comment, but it may cause strange behaviour when being used within a parenthesised block of code…

Answer (score 1):

`:` in bash is not exactly a comment. It is a void command.
A little bit like `pass` in some languages.

It helps, for example, to fill empty slots, if needed

```bash
if condition
then
    :
else
    doSomething
fi
```

So, you may use, somehow, as a sort of comment. That would works both in bash and batch (well, I know nothing of batch. But since you said that `::` is a comment there). But beware that it is not exactly a comment. So there are some differences

For example

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo one ||
:: foo
echo two

echo un ||
# bar
echo deux
```

Displays `one`, `two` and `un` but not `deux`.

Because `echo one ||` prints `one` and then execute the following command only if it fails (which it doesn't). Here the following command is `:: foo`. Which is not executed (you wouldn't know, since it does nothing, but it is not executed). And the `echo two` is a brand new unrelated command that is executed.

Whereas, on the other hand, `echo un ||` likewise prints `un`, and doesn't execute the next command, since `echo un` did not fail. But the next command here is `echo deux`. Because `# bar` doesn't count, since it is a comment.

And that is only one of the many examples one could probably find to show that `:` is not a comment.

But, well, if you use it being aware of that, I suppose you could use it to insert void comments in your bash code that would also be void in batch.

Edit:
I won't edit for each new example that comes to mind. But that one is pretty important

```bash
echo un # deux
echo one : two
```

prints

```
un
one : two
```

`:` is a command. So, as other commands, like `ls` not all occurrence of it is treated as so (no more than `echo ls` list the directory constant. `ls` is just a string here)

So, you can't use it as a replacement for inline comments. Only for full lines comments.

Comment: Please note that `:` is not used alone but in combination with `: ;#`, i.e. the so called POSIX special buil-in alias for true, followed by a command separator and comment out the rest of the line

Comment: @wolfrevo You mean that it is not necessarily used alone, I guess. Because you can use it alone. Obviously, the usage I am suggesting here is not what it is made for. It is not meant to be a comment. It is not meant to be used alone. But in combination with if, for or other control. But it doesn't mean that it cannot be used alone, and that the usage I suggest, alone as an alternative comment is not valid. It is valid. Strange, but valid. And I was under the impression that you were looking for some sort of way to have void statement in both languages.

Comment: Obviously, comment in bash is with `#`. But your question was to find something else. All answer can only be strange.